# SDK: filtering a rallycardboard

Tags: rally

How do you filter the cards in a rallycardboard using the SDK?

It seems simple enough, using the filter() function (though I'm not sure why there does not seem to be an option in the configs), but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
    var cardBoardConfig = {
            xtype: 'rallycardboard',
            types: ['PortfolioItem/Feature'],
            columns: initiativeColumns,
            attribute: 'Parent',
            context: context
        };
    var cardBoard = this.add(cardBoardConfig);
    var releaseFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter',
            { property: 'Release.Name', operator: '!=', value: ''});


    cardBoard.filter(releaseFilter);
```

I realize the filter it is looking for is actually a Ext.util.filter, but variants with that don't seem to work either.  For example, I have tried:

```
    var releaseFilter = Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', { property: 'Release', operator: '=', value: null});
```

My goal here is to filter the cards based on whether they are assigned to a particular release or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [source for CardBoard's filter](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/source/CardBoard.html#Rally-ui-cardboard-CardBoard-method-filter), you'll see that it's not implemented yet. That's pretty bad and we should fix that.

It looks like you can use `cardboard.applyFilters([filter])` as an alternative. If that doesn't work, then this should work as a server side approach:

```
var cardBoardConfig = {
    xtype: 'rallycardboard',
    types: ['PortfolioItem/Feature'],
    columns: initiativeColumns,
    attribute: 'Parent',
    context: context,
    // have the server do the filtering
    storeConfig: {
        filters: [
            { property: 'Release.Name', operator: '!=', value: ''}
        ]
    }
};
var cardBoard = this.add(cardBoardConfig);
```

Comment: Thanks-- the cardboard seems more beta than most...updates would be appreciated.  I had to use the "storeConfig" variant above because applyFilters() did not seem to work.  Also, I found that I needed to add a "context" to the storeConfig because setting context in the cardboard config did not seem to work.  Finally, there are some problems when moving cards from one cardbard to the other-- I have the drag/drop event set the "Release" field, but then the updated card still appears in the source cardboard, even though the filters should screen it out.